# Trademark Licencee rights

Tags: trademark

I have held a trademark licence for 20 years and have recently had it cancelled by the owner of the trademark. It is my understanding that I did not breach any of the conditions.  I am wondering if that is legal action by the owner to break the agreement without valid reason?

Comment: We would have to read the license to be able to make any constructive comment on the question at hand.

Comment: Please don't solicit legal advice from users here, either. It's not what the site is for; if you don't think you can afford a lawyer to check this, you definitely can't afford not a lawyer to check it.

Comment: I do not think this is asking for specific legal advice, and it should not IMO be closed on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

A license (trademark or copyright) may be permanent, for a fixed term, or cancelable at will or for cause by the rights-holder. If the terms provide that the license could only be canceled for cause then you might have a claim. If the terms were that it could be canceled at will, or had to be renewed on a regular basis, then the rights-holder would have been entitled to cancel. Without seeing the license agreement, there is no way to tell what it permits.

If the agreement did not specify, it is probably subject to cancellation at will, at least in the US. The law of the particular country may affect such default provisions. Trademark law, in particular, varies by country.